# Oauth2 additional parameter validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, oauth, access-token

I have added additional parameter to my authentication which is discipline(Football, Voleyball).

- xyz@abc.com with discipline FOOTBALL
- xyz@abc.com with discipline HANDBALL

accounts are two different(not connected) but Oauth2 response with the same access and refresh tokens. I've tried to debug that and noticed that objects are correct(have different discipline value) but probably its validated only by username.

Thats my userDetails class which is correctly converted and returns user with correct discipline from method loadUserByUsername from implemented UserDetailsService.

```
public class UserLoggedDetails implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    public UserLoggedDetails() {

    }
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1517854890490461015L;

    @Transient
    private List<GrantedAuthority> auths;

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    private String password;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    private String username;

    private String remoteId;

    private Discipline discipline;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.auths;
    }

    public void setAuths(List<GrantedAuthority> auths) {
        this.auths = auths;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public String getRemoteId() {
        return remoteId;
    }

    public void setRemoteId(String remoteId) {
        this.remoteId = remoteId;
    }

    public Discipline getDiscipline() {
        return discipline;
    }

    public void setDiscipline(Discipline discipline) {
        this.discipline = discipline;
    }
}
```